# How to create an Hstore column type in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, hstore

I'm using the Schema Builder inside of Migrations in Laravel 4 to manage my Postgres database during development. I've run into a problem. I want to utilize the Postgres Hstore column type in my table but I can't figure it out.

There doesn't seem to be a "custom" column type in the Schema Builder (that I can find), so this was my attempt inside of a migration. This didn't work for me.

```
Schema::create('entities', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('data')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
DB::raw("ALTER TABLE `entities` CHANGE COLUMN `data` `data` hstore NULL;");
```

I also tried this instead of the last command. No luck.

```
DB::raw("ALTER TABLE `entities` ALTER `data` TYPE hstore;");
```

Note: I did already run the command `CREATE EXTENSION hstore` in my database.

Comment: I was able to get it working using the following command (looks I had the wrong method and was off on the SQL).

`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE entities ALTER attributes TYPE hstore USING (attributes::hstore);");`

It'd be nice if Laravel incorporated custom column types.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the `Builder::blueprintResolver` function

```
$builder = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

    $builder->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
        return new CustomPostgresBlueprint($table, $callback);
    });

    $builder->create('record_sets', function(CustomPostgresBlueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->hstore('schema');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

You'll also need to implement a typeHstore function within a custom `PostgresGrammer` subclass. FOr full implementation details, look [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=38809#p38809)