# how to implement hstore in Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm using `Laravel` and `Postgres` in my project. What is the best way to add `hstore` column type in laravel migration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an Hstore column type in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079840/how-to-create-an-hstore-column-type-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Or take a look at this package https://github.com/bosnadev/database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079840/how-to-create-an-hstore-column-type-in-laravel-4   the example link in this question is not working

Comment: with Bosnadev package ```$table->hstore('sample')->nullable()->default('');```

Comment: @Mohammadb Does this package support Laravel 8x?